Stucco Repair and Deck Ledgerboard Replacement
I'd like a little review on my plan to replace the ledger board for my deck (that has collapsed and been demo'd).
The house was built in 1964 with rear deck that was a 2" concrete slab deck on timber framing. The support structure was already sketchy looking when we moved in 4 years ago, but this summer it finally started collapsing completely. I decided to do a full demo of the deck and replace it with an open deck.
I plan on completely removing the existing ledger board, as (like the rest of the wood) it is completely rotted out in places. The plan is:

Use a diamond blade masonry saw to cut through the stucco about 4-6" above the existing flashing. (No asbestos in stucco - I had it tested - will still wear P100 mask)
Remove the existing flashing, and reseal under the paper barrier as best as I can. (I've seen youtube videos of people doing this, but am not 100% which products to use).
Install new metal flashing above the new ledger board, and below it above the concrete/stucco.

I'm generally trying to follow this guide and particular this diagram:

Here are some pictures of the existing stucco/ledger board:





I think this should work, but I've never done this before and am looking for advice.
